# Plugins in my Debian Nagios VM on ESXi time out

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi, timeout

I have a working Debian Nagios server on a VirtualBox VM. All works perfectly and I have no time out executing my plugins.
I want to add it to my ESXi 5.5 so I convert the VirtualBox VM into a VMware VM using this tutorial : [Link](https://felixcentmerino.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/migrate-virtual-machine-from-oracle-virtualbox-to-esxi-5-5/)

It works great and my VM is correctly added to the ESXi.
I can access to the Nagios web interface with its local IP address.

But actually randomly plugins time out. The CPU is no longer accessible or the server I monitor is shown disconnected. When I re check the plugin everything goes back to normal.

How to make plugins answer as fast as they used to be?
Should I increase timeout? But it is not normal that sockets take more than 10 seconds to answer.

Comment: Have you tried just creating the VM in an ESXi native VM rather than via this conversion method - or try using VMware's own converter tool?

Comment: I used the OVF VMware tool. I didn't try to create an ESXi native VM because I would have to reinstall and configure everything and it would takes a lot of time. Could it also be that my VM was in 64 bits and I think my ESXi is on 32 bits ?

Comment: ESXi is 64-bit only.

Comment: Ok thank you Chopper. I added 4 Gb of RAM (from 1Gb), keep one processor, set the OS to be Other (64 bits) (from Other (32 bits)) because the only Debian choice is Debian 5 and I have 8. I did a speed test and I got a ping of 3 ms and 8 Mbps in download and 70 Mbps in upload. I still have socket timeout I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution : First when I modify theses parameters it was still laggy but after a reboot and wait a few minutes all back to normal.

First I installed VMware tools for Debian using this command : `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools`

Then I added 4 Gb of RAM (from 1Gb), keep one processor, set the OS to be Other (64 bits) (from Other (32 bits))

Comment: Oh, so it was simply that you hadn't done the most basic thing you do with a VMware VM, that was straightforward - at least you got it fixed.